# Linking Wikipedia articles in different languages

Tags: wikipedia

Wikipedia pages have the article in different languages on the left pane.
How does this linking work?

I have also noticed that the language options change when you go to one that is listed there. Are the pages listed in the page's plain text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used to have to add language links in the article text, but that has not been true for the last few years.

Interlanguage links are managed from the [Wikidata](https://www.wikidata.org) specialty site.

Find the specific topic you want to add an interlanguage link to on Wikidata (e.g., [Beer](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q44)) and add the correct link in the proper format.

*Much* more information is available from [Wikipedia Help](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Interlanguage_links).